# Laravel - Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a PHP library in Laravel. I want to call a variable that is global to my function and I get this error.

**Using $this when not in object context**

Where am I missing?

```
class ConfigurationProvider implements ConfigurationProvider
{
    protected $conf;

    private function getCredentials()
    {
        return $this->conf;
    }

}
```

**My Controller**

```
public function testApi(){
        $object = ConfigurationProvider::getCredentials();
        return $object;
}
```

Comment: You are calling the function statically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're treating `getCredentials()` as a static method. Static method do not have access to the object. Just static properties.

```
class ConfigurationProvider implements ConfigurationProvider
{
    protected static $conf;

    private static function getCredentials()
    {
        return self::$conf;
    }
}
```

```php
$object = ConfigurationProvider::getCredentials();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate your object, then call the method

```
public function testApi() 
{
   $configProvider = new ConfigurationProvider();
   $object = $configProvider->getCredentials();
   return $object;
}
```